# 'Deep water' is a/the story

Tags: articles, adjective-phrases

Read the following sentences

' Deep Water ' is a story about Michael's childhood .

' Deep Water ' is the story about Michael's childhood .

How are they two different

I just want to know how a noun modified by an adjective phrase changes when I change its article

Comment: Please familiarize and mind the formatting of your questions, for example, punctuation marks, quotes, etc. otherwise it may attract downvotes. Please also have a look at [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/editing-help) article about formatting. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of 'a' and 'the'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/256471/usage-of-a-and-the)

Answer (score 1):

> "Deep Water" is a story about Michael's childhood

implies that "Deep Water" is only one of many stories about Michael's childhood. They may be actual stories already written, or only potential stories, but the sentence implies that there is more than one, perhaps many.

> "Deep Water" is the story about Michael's childhood.

implies tht "Deep Water" is the singular such story.

Comment: Someone told me that the first sentence could mean that there are several Stories in the world and that deep water is one of those stories and that it concerns Michael's childhood.

Comment: Btw I'm not doubting your answer because I thought it the same way, but someone told me this, please tell me if it is correct

Comment: Yes, it could be interpreted that way. Also, it would be more usual to say _'Deep Water' is the story **of** Michael's childhood_ if it gave a full account of his childhood years.